# Create a C# method that accepts multiple types of objects?

Tags: c#, oop

I am writing a class to handle my data transactions.  I want to create a method to handle multiple objects instead of having a different method for every object type.

For example, say I have object types: Car, Truck, House.  Each object has a property holding the names of the fields and types that should go in to creating a database.  Likewise, each object has a method called PrintFieldsWithType() to print those out as part of an SQL query.

I've been trying something like:

```
private void CreateTable(string tblname, Object tempobject)
    {
        //Construct Command String from Params
        string mycommand = "CREATE TABLE " + tblname + tempobject.PrintFieldsWithType();
        tempobject = null;
        //Construct object and execute query
        command = new SQLiteCommand(mycommand, myconnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Instead of creating a different method for each object type, I would like to be able to call this method like:
CreateTable(NewCars, Car myCar);
CreateTable(CheapHouses, House myHouse);

Am I attempting to handle this the wrong way?
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I attempting to handle this the wrong way?

Yes, because `Object` does not contain a definition for `PrintFieldsWithType` so your code will not compile.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Create an interface that defines the properties/methods that are common to those types:

```
public interface IThing //(please come up with a better name)
{
    public string PrintFieldsWithType();
}
```

and have each type implement that interface:

```
public class Car : IThing
```

etc.

then change `CreateTable` to

```
private void CreateTable(string tblname, IThing tempobject)
```

If the *implementation* of `PrintFieldsWithType` is *exactly* the same for each type then you can make it a base class instead of an interface, but since a class can only have one direct base class but can implement multiple interfaces, you need to choose wisely.

Comment: `IFieldsWithTypePrinter`? ^^

Comment: So THAT's what interfaces are for. Thanks!